# cannot be resolved or is not a field WebView object

Tags: android

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

gives me webView1 cannot be resolved or is not a field, I don't know why. Here's my XML:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I eventually want this simple line of code to be executed:

```
wv.loadUrl("http://www.cinicraft.com/pick.html");
```

Comment: I assume you have tried rebuilding and cleaning the project and also that you have `import android.webkit.WebView;` in import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an automatic build you can check?  Also, try cleaning the project, that usually fixes these kinds of errors for me.